# Token [current-page:url] is missing the language prefix in multi-language site setup

Tags: views, 9, tokens

Using Drupal v9.4 and Token v1.10.0, the `[current-page:url]` doesn't seem to include the language prefix.

The setup is I have two languages: English and Spanish. I created a View where the path is `/articles` so I am able to access the View page using `/en/articles` and `/en-gb/articles`. I then added a Canonical URL using the Metatags module using the said token but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are missing a question. Anyways, I think there was an issue on DO. Also try https://www.drupal.org/project/token_language.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use current page url, you could use `[current-request:uri]` for multilingal page.

e.g.

- access to `https://example.com/en`, `[current-request:uri]` reveals `https://example.com/en`